# multiple custom plugins in py.test

Tags: python, pytest

My question is regarding multiple custom plugins in pytest. 
I have two (or more) pytest plugins that I created which are installed using setuptools and pytest11 entry point, each plugin has its own setup.py.  It seems like only the first installed plugin is active. I have verified this via print statements in the pytest_configure hook.  If the first installed plugin is uninstalled, then only the second configure hook for the second plugin seems to get called.  Also, the same behavior is observed with the addoption hook, options for the plugin installed second is unrecognized.
I'm thoroughly confused because I've used third party plugins and they seem to work just fine.  Aren't hooks for all the installed plugins supposed to be called ? 
Could this be a problem with the way plugins are installed, i.e. with setuptools ? (the command I use is python setup.py -v install).  Pip correctly shows all the plugin modules as installed.

Edit: 
Names are different, below are the setup files:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="pytest_suite",
    version="0.1",
    packages=['suite_util'],
    # the following makes a plugin available to pytest
    entry_points={
        'pytest11': [
            'name_of_plugin = suite_util.conftest',
        ]
    },
)
```

and

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="pytest_auto_framework",
    version="0.1",
    packages=['automation_framework'],
    # the following makes a plugin available to pytest
    entry_points={
         'pytest11': [
         'name_of_plugin = automation_framework.conftest',
    ]
    },
 )
```

Comment: Can you post the two setup.py files? Are you using different plugin names for each?

Comment: specifying pytest_plugins in conftest.py in the test dir seems to do the trick (pytest doc specifies that plugins set to pytest_plugins are loaded when the conftest loads).  however, is this a requirement ? shouldnt all the installed plugins be active already ?

pytest_plugins = "automation_framework.conftest", "suite_util.conftest"

Comment: Are those the actual setup files you are using? Both have the same plugin name: `name_of_plugin`. Otherwise, can you post a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

If your pytest entry points both have the same name (as they do in your example above), [only the first one will be loaded by pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py#L492-L506).

Note that [this is not an inherent limitation of `pkg_resources` entry points](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#entry-points) but due to they way plugins are registered in pytest. There can only be one plugin with the same name - which makes sense imho.

Answer (score 0):

The Pytest official document is ambiguous. The reason why your code don't work is because you followed that doc when you writing your both setup.py with same plugin name:
In this code:

```py
entry_points={
         'pytest11': [
         'name_of_plugin = automation_framework.conftest',
    ]
```

the `name_of_plugin` is customizble and should be unique, otherwise pytest will load one of all plugins with same name (I guess is the last one with same name)

So, the solution to your question is:

**setup.py 1:**

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="pytest_auto_framework",
    version="0.1",
    packages=['automation_framework'],
    # the following makes a plugin available to pytest
    entry_points={
         'pytest11': [
         'automation_framework = automation_framework.conftest',
    ]
    },
 )
```

**setup.py 2:**

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="pytest_suite",
    version="0.1",
    packages=['suite_util'],
    # the following makes a plugin available to pytest
    entry_points={
        'pytest11': [
            'suite_util = suite_util.conftest',
        ]
    },
)
```

**POC**
[2 entry points with same plugin name left hand value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZSau.jpg)

[2 engry points with different plugin name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg5li.png)